# how to add user defined type attribute in proto(Google Protocol Buffer) programatically

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I want to create .proto file through java code. I am able to do it with message having primitive type attributes as follow :

```
public void testDynamicProto() throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = buildPersonProtoDesc();
    byte[] personBytes = buildPersonProto(bytes);

    Descriptors.FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = Descriptors.FileDescriptor
            .buildFrom(
                    DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto.parseFrom(bytes),
                    new Descriptors.FileDescriptor[0]);

    Descriptors.Descriptor personDesc = fileDescriptor
            .findMessageTypeByName(PERSON_MESSAGE);
    DynamicMessage message = DynamicMessage.parseFrom(personDesc,
            personBytes);
    for (Map.Entry<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, Object> entry : message
            .getAllFields().entrySet()) {
        // TODO: add asserts
        System.out.println(entry.getKey().getName() + "------------"
                + entry.getValue());
    }

    // TODO: test repeated field
    // TODO: test non destructive updates (addition of column) to person proto and make sure old protos can be parsed
}


private byte[] buildPersonProto(byte[] bytes)
        throws Descriptors.DescriptorValidationException,
        InvalidProtocolBufferException {
    Descriptors.FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = Descriptors.FileDescriptor
            .buildFrom(
                    DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto.parseFrom(bytes),
                    new Descriptors.FileDescriptor[0]);

    Descriptors.Descriptor personDesc = fileDescriptor
            .findMessageTypeByName(PERSON_MESSAGE);

    DynamicMessage.Builder personBuilder = DynamicMessage
            .newBuilder(personDesc);
    personBuilder.setField(personDesc.findFieldByName(FNAME_FIELD), "Jon");
    personBuilder.setField(personDesc.findFieldByName(LNAME_FIELD), "Doe");
    personBuilder.setField(personDesc.findFieldByName(STATUS_FIELD), 2);


    return personBuilder.build().toByteArray();
}

private byte[] buildPersonProtoDesc() {
    DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto.Builder fileDescriptorProtoBuilder = DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto
            .newBuilder();
    DescriptorProtos.DescriptorProto.Builder messageProtoBuilderA = DescriptorProtos.DescriptorProto
            .newBuilder();
    messageProtoBuilderA.setName(PERSON_MESSAGE);
    messageProtoBuilderA
            .addFieldBuilder()
            .setName(FNAME_FIELD)
            .setNumber(1)
            .setType(DescriptorProtos.FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TYPE_STRING);
    messageProtoBuilderA
            .addFieldBuilder()
            .setName(LNAME_FIELD)
            .setNumber(2)
            .setType(DescriptorProtos.FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TYPE_STRING);
    messageProtoBuilderA.addFieldBuilder().setName(STATUS_FIELD)
            .setNumber(3)
            .setType(DescriptorProtos.FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TYPE_INT32);



    fileDescriptorProtoBuilder.addMessageType(messageProtoBuilderA);
    DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto fileDescriptorProto = fileDescriptorProtoBuilder
            .build();
    return fileDescriptorProto.toByteArray();
}
```

Now my proto structure is

```
message Person{

optional string FName=1;
optional string LName=2;
optional string Status=3;}
```

And I can achieve this by using above methods.

**I want to achieve:**

```
message Person{

optional string FName=1;
optional string LName=2;
optional string Status=3;

message Address {

    optional string country=1;
    optional string state=2;
    optional string city=3;}

repeated Address address=4;}
```

Queries:

1. How to add Address under Person(can try method **addRepeatedField** but couldn't create FileDescriptor)
2. How to add Address as repeated field(ArrayList) under Person

Please give me any hint if anybody has.

Answer (score 0):

To add a type under `Person` call `addNestedType()` on `messageProtoBuilderA` (the `DescriptorProto.Builder` for Person). The input for addNestedType() is a DescriptorProto for `Address`, which is built in the same way as the one for `Person`.

When adding the `address` field to the Person type, call `setLabel(Label.LABEL_REPEATED)` on the corresponding `FieldDescriptorProto.Builder`.

```
DescriptorProto.Builder messageProtoBuilderA = ...;
messageProtoBuilderA.addNestedType(createAddressType());

FieldDescriptorProto.Builder addressField = FieldDescriptorProto.newBuilder();
addressField.setName("address")
            .setLabel(Label.LABEL_REPEATED)
            .setNumber(4)
            .setType(Type.TYPE_MESSAGE)
            .setTypeName("Address");
messageProtoBuilderA.addField(addressField);
...

private DescriptorProto.Builder createAddressType() {
    DescriptorProto.Builder addressProtoBuilder = DescriptorProto.newBuilder();
    addressProtoBuilder.setName("Address");
    // add fields
    return addressProtoBuilder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe for protos all the fields have to be together. So it should be

```
optional string FName=1;
optional string LName=2;
optional string Status=3;
repeated Address address=4;
```

and you can put this under your definition of Address so that code is already generated.